# Is this a video of severe turbulence for an Airbus A320? (video)

Tags: aircraft-design

I remember reading that in 1966, a 707 encountered turbulence and the wings and tail were torn off (BOAC 911). Is this video at all comparable? Is the A320 more robust than the 707?

Comment: "a 707 encountered this exact type of turbulence" how can you be sure that is was the "exact type of turbulence"? and of the same strength/intensity?

Comment: Winds at the peak of Mt. Fuji were recorded at around 60-70 knots. (70-80 mph). BOAC 911 was at around 16,000 feet where the air is about half as thin as the altitude this flight was at (close to sea level; coming in to land), and they registered over 50 miles an hour at sea level. I'd say the intensity of loads put on the fin was comparable when accounting for air density.

Comment: @Warden A constant wind does **not** put any load on a wing because the aircraft flies within the moving air. Only wind speed (or direction) *changes* (turbulence) are relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I was referring to gusts.

Comment: without any numbers and sources, that's just speculation and wishful thinking.

Comment: Given that BOAC 911's FDR couldn't be retrieved, all we can do is speculate. Even the Wikipedia article is mostly speculation due to lack of FDR data. This was back in 1966.

Comment: There is no evidence what happened in the video was caused by turbulence. If you look at the flight control surfaces, it appears it was all a result of pilot control inputs. Nothing in that video would even suggest a structure failure was imminent.

Comment: If aircraft were built so they would fall apart every time they wobbled from side to side a bit, I doubt the aircraft industry would be as successful as it is today-

Comment: The video refers to BA492 on Feb. 25th.  Here is more info: 
 https://www.aviationcv.com/aviation-blog/2019/british-airways-flight-ba-492-extreme-wind

Comment: I think this question seems reasonable, on topic, clearly written, and interesting, so I'm giving it an upvote.

Comment: @abelenky Does your edit reflect the intention of the QE? And isn't it a bit fishy to adapt the question to your own answer? Just wondering...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the cause of this roll oscillation during BA492 go-around? (closed)](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/60522)

Answer (score 7):

That is not strong turbulence.

It is not strong turbulence because the passenger keeps both feet on the floor, and is able to hold his phone relatively steady.

In severe turbulence, everything is thrown around the cabin:  bins pop open, cell phones are ripped from hands and become projectiles, luggage flies across the plane, people are thrown to the ceiling if not buckled in, and if they are buckled in, their knees hit their chest with considerable force.  In severe turbulence, broken bones, concussions, and spinal injuries are common.

Even in those conditions, airplanes do not break apart.  Turbulence strong enough to destroy an airplane would leave everyone inside the plane, including the pilots, unconscious and severely injured.

That the passengers on this flight could speak, sit upright, and film indicates that this turbulence was mild-to-moderate at worst.

---

Think of severe turbulence like this:

Have you ever been in a relatively low-speed car crash (around 20-30 MPH), where the airbags go off, the glove box pops open, you hit your arms on the dash, and everything loose in the car goes flying?

Severe turbulence is like being on an amusement park roller-coaster, with lots of shaking, dives, climbs, and turns while ***also*** being in a car crash every 10 seconds.  The average turbulence is shaking you around constantly so all you can do is hold on, and several times a minute you also get a big jolt similar to a car crash!

Answer (score 3):

It did not break up, because it is designed and built strong enough to withstand this kind of load - and quite a lot more.

Aircraft wings also have to pass wing bending stress tests. Here is a catchy video on [bending the wings of an A350](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--LTYRTKV_A).